# How can I use a temporary file descriptor with ecryptfs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, mount, ecryptfs

I'd like to be able to run a script, have it prompt me for my password, and then mount an `ecryptfs` directory. I do not want the password to sit around on the file system, or show up in logs, `ps`, etc. I thought I could use a temporary file descriptor for this; however, `ecryptfs` returns an error with the following statements.

```
willi@hostname:~$ exec 3<<<"passphrase_passwd="$(zenity --password)
willi@hostname:~$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_cipher=aes,\
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,\
  ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=1234678765432345678,\
  key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_fd=3 /mountpoint/ /mountpoint/
Error attempting to evaluate mount options: [-1] Operation not permitted
Check your system logs for details on why this happened.
Try updating your ecryptfs-utils package, and/or
submit a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs
```

After the error is returned, I can verify that `ecryptfs` did not read the file descriptor, because the password is still sitting in it:

```
willi@hostname:~$ cat <&3
passphrase_passwd=test
```

I reviewed the approach in [encryptfs auto-mounting script](https://serverfault.com/questions/383709/encryptfs-auto-mounting-script?rq=1); though I'd like to avoid having the password in a file on the file system.

I'm using version 103 of `ecryptfs-utils`:

```
willi@hostname:~$ ecryptfsd --version
ecryptfsd (ecryptfs-utils) 103

This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

How can I use the temporary file descriptor with `ecryptfs`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the fact that I was running `zenity` as a normal user, and then using `sudo` to execute the mount command. When I stuck both commands in a script and ran the entire script as root, things worked perfectly.